# Relation between discrete uniform and binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose $X\sim D-unif(1,n)$ and $Y \sim Bin(n,p)$. What is the relation between these two distribution?

Comment: I know each distribution very well. But still can't find a relation between these two.

Comment: maybe the relation is conditional probability?

Comment: What do you mean by $D$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur D-unif = discrete uniform here.

Comment: They have in common that they are both discrete and take values in natural numbers. That's all I can think of.

Comment: I would say that a random variable with binomial distribution is the sum of random variables with an alternative distribution. The alternative distribution is actually a uniform two-state distribution with P (1) = p and P (0) = 1-p.